# How do i gain access to grouped data?

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I have two records that I have attempted to join and group. I am now trying to project the data into another record. The problem is that I can't figure out how to gain access to the grouped properties.
Here is the code:

first record:

```
type Product = {
    Id : string;
    Name : string;
    Description : string;
}
```

second record:

```
type ProductOption = {
    Id : string;
    ProductId : string;
    SizeId : int;
    Price : decimal;
}
```

final record:

```
type ProductDetails = {
    Product : Product;
    Options : seq<ProductOption>;
}
```

this is my groupBy code:

```
let getProductDetails = 
    query{
        for row in productRecords do
        join opt in productOptionRecords on
           (row.Id = opt.ProductId)
        groupBy row.Id into prod
        // here is my problem, this below does not work
        select {
                  Product = prod.Product,
                  Options = prod.ProductOption
               }
     }
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that what you are looking for, is the `groupJoin`-operator. The below code compiles, and as we all knows, then it is almost surely correct.;) You'd better check, though. I haven't tested it on any actual data.

```
query{
    for prod in productRecords do
    groupJoin opt in productOptionRecords on
        (prod.Id = opt.ProductId) into prodopts
    select {
              Product = prod;
              Options = prodopts
           }
 }
```

Comment: By the way, I suppose you could use a `leftOuterJoin` instead. But since you were originally trying to use `join` and `groupBy`, `groupJoin` is probably the way to go. Also, I think it is the easiest.